# Optimize an objective function with eigenvalues constraints in Python

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I would like to find a square matrix that:

1. optimizes (minimizes) an objective function
2. has all his eigenvalues bounded by some value

What I have done:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, NonlinearConstraint

def min_eigenval(A):

    x = np.linalg.eigvals(A)
    return np.amin(x)

def my_minimizer(eig_bnd, A): # A is a square matrix
    
    Z = np.zeros(A.shape)
    nlc = NonlinearConstraint(min_eigenval,eig_bnd, np.inf) # Constraint I want: min_eigenval >= eig_bnd
    def obj_fun(x):
        y = np.linalg.norm(x - A)
        return y*y
    sol = minimize(obj_fun, Z, method='SLSQP', options={'ftol': 1e-10,'disp': False}, constraints=nlc)

    return sol['x']

A = np.array([[2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 2]])
B = my_minimizer(1, A)
print(B)
```

Note that the matrices aren't always diagonal. I have used them as an example so that calculating their eigenvalues is easy. So I would like B = I in this specific example.

However, I get the following error:
*`x0` must have at most 1 dimension*

I saw that the problem is when scipy tries to approximate the derivative. Which makes sense because the constraint function isn't differentiable.

My question is how to formulate the constraint, or what module to use instead to overcome the problem.

Comment: `minimize` docs make it quite clear that `x0` has to have shape `(n,)`, i.e. 1d.  If you it helps you to think of `Z` as 2d, you'll need to use the appropriate `reshape` or `ravel`s to flip back and forth between what `minimize` uses, and what your functions need.

Comment: @hpaulj So you are suggesting to do something like Z = Z.flatten() and within min_eigenval to do the reverse of flatten()?

Comment: I would use `ravel` or `reshape`, since they don't make a copy (`flatten` always makes a copy).  Just pay attention to the shape of `x` that's passed to the objective function and constraint function(s).